# Find specific columns and replace the following column with specific value with gawk

Tags: replace, awk, gawk

I am trying to find all the places where my data has a repeating line and delete the repeating line.  Also, I am looking for where the 2nd column has the value 90 and replace the following 2nd column with a specific number I designate.

My data looks like this:

```
 #      Type    Response        Acc     RT      Offset    
   1      70  0    0   0.0000 57850
   2      31  0    0   0.0000 59371
   3      41  0    0   0.0000 60909
   4      70  0    0   0.0000 61478
   5      31  0    0   0.0000 62999 
   6      41  0    0   0.0000 64537
   7      41  0    0   0.0000 64537
   8      70  0    0   0.0000 65106
   9      11  0    0   0.0000 66627
  10      21  0    0   0.0000 68165
  11      90  0    0   0.0000 68700
  12      31  0    0   0.0000 70221
```

I want my data to look like:

```
 #      Type    Response        Acc     RT      Offset
   1      70  0    0   0.0000 57850
   2      31  0    0   0.0000 59371
   3      41  0    0   0.0000 60909
   4      70  0    0   0.0000 61478
   5      31  0    0   0.0000 62999
   6      41  0    0   0.0000 64537
   8      70  0    0   0.0000 65106
   9      11  0    0   0.0000 66627
  10      21  0    0   0.0000 68165
  11      90  0    0   0.0000 68700
  12       5  0    0   0.0000 70221
```

My code:

```
 BEGIN {
priorline = "";
ERROROFFSET = 50;
ERRORVALUE[10] = 1;
ERRORVALUE[11] = 2;
ERRORVALUE[12] = 3;
ERRORVALUE[30] = 4;
ERRORVALUE[31] = 5;
ERRORVALUE[32] = 6;

ORS = "\n";
}

NR == 1 {
print;
getline;
priorline = $0;
}

NF == 6 {

brandnewline = $0
mytype = $2
$0 = priorline
priorField2 = $2;   

if (mytype !~ priorField2) {
print;
priorline = brandnewline;
}

if (priorField2 == "90") {
    mytype = ERRORVALUE[mytype];
    }
}

END {print brandnewline}


##Here the parameters of the brandnewline is set to the current line and then the
##proirline is set to the line on which we just worked on and the brandnewline is
##set to be the next new line we are working on. (i.e line 1 = brandnewline, now
##we set priorline = brandnewline, thus priorline is line 1 and brandnewline takes
##on line 2) Next, the same parameters were set with column 2, mytype being the 
##current column 2 value and priorField2 being the same value as mytype moves to
##the next column 2 value.  Finally, we wrote an if statement where, if the value
##in column 2 of the current line !~ (does not equal) value of column two of the
##previous line, then the current line will be print otherwise it will just be
##skipped over.  The second if statement recognizes the lines in which the value
##90 appeared and replaces the value in column 2 with a previously defined
##ERRORVALUE set for each specific type (type 10=1, 11=2,12=3, 30=4, 31=5, 32=6).
```

I have been able to successfully delete the repeating lines, however, I am unable to execute the next part of my code, which is to replace the values I designated in BEGIN as the ERRORVALUES (10=1, 11=2, 12=3, 30=4, 31=5, 32=6) with the actual columns that contain that value.  Essentially, I want to just replace that value in the line with my ERRORVALUE.

If anyone can help me with this I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One challenge is that you can't just compare one line with the previous because the ID number will be different.

```
awk '
  BEGIN {
    ERRORVALUE[10] = 1
    # ... etc
  }

  # print the header
  NR == 1 {print; next}

  NR == 2 || $0 !~ prev_regex {
    prev_regex = sprintf("^\\s+\\w+\\s+%s\\s+%s\\s+%s\\s+%s\\s+%s",$2,$3,$4,$5,$6)
    if (was90) $2 = ERRORVALUE[$2]
    print
    was90 = ($2 == 90)
  }
'
```

For lines where the 2nd column is altered, this ruins the line formatting:

```
 #      Type    Response        Acc     RT      Offset
   1      70  0    0   0.0000 57850
   2      31  0    0   0.0000 59371
   3      41  0    0   0.0000 60909
   4      70  0    0   0.0000 61478
   5      31  0    0   0.0000 62999
   6      41  0    0   0.0000 64537
   8      70  0    0   0.0000 65106
   9      11  0    0   0.0000 66627
  10      21  0    0   0.0000 68165
  11      90  0    0   0.0000 68700
12 5 0 0 0.0000 70221
```

If that's a problem, you could pipe the output of gawk into [`column -t`](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=column), or if you know the line format is fixed, use printf() in the awk program.

Comment: First: Thank you so much for your answer it has been very helpful. Also, thank you for such a speedy reply. Second: One concern I have is if it is possible that instead of the line after I see a 90 in $2 that I substitute whats in $2 two lines before? In this example you see 90 in $2 in line 11 is it possible to alter $2 in line 9 to the formatting described in BEGIN, and if so how would I go about doing this?

Comment: I'd probably take 2 passes over your file: `awk 'remove duplicate lines' | tac | awk 'replace $2 if value 2 lines before is 90' | tac` -- tac is a handy utility to print a file from the last line to the first. Otherwise, the awk script is turning into a bit of a mess with having to remember now 2 previous lines, taking care that 2 lines ago was not deleted, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
v=99999
sed ':a;$!N;s/^\(\s*\S*\s*\)\(.*\)\s*\n.*\2/\1\2/;ta;s/^\(\s*\S*\s*\)   90 /\1'"$(printf "%5d" $v)"' /;P;D' file
 #      Type    Response        Acc     RT      Offset    
   1      70  0    0   0.0000 57850
   2      31  0    0   0.0000 59371
   3      41  0    0   0.0000 60909
   4      70  0    0   0.0000 61478
   5      31  0    0   0.0000 62999 
   6      41  0    0   0.0000 64537
   8      70  0    0   0.0000 65106
   9      11  0    0   0.0000 66627
  10      21  0    0   0.0000 68165
  11   99999  0    0   0.0000 68700
  12      31  0    0   0.0000 70221
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
        ERROROFFSET = 50;
        ERRORVALUE[10] = 1;
        ERRORVALUE[11] = 2;
        ERRORVALUE[12] = 3;
        ERRORVALUE[30] = 4;
        ERRORVALUE[31] = 5;
        ERRORVALUE[32] = 6;
     }
     NR == 1 { print ; next }
     { if (a[$2 $6]) { next } else { a[$2 $6]++ }
       if ( $2 == 90) { print ; n++ ; next } 
       if (n>0) { $2 = ERRORVALUE[$2] ; n=0 }
       printf("% 4i% 8i%  3i% 5i% 9.4f% 6i\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6)
     }' INPUTFILE
```

[See it in action here at ideone.com](http://ideone.com/8zErW).

IMO the `BEGIN` block is obvious. Then the following happens:

1. the `NR == 1` line prints the very first line (and switches to the next line, also this rule only apply to the very first line)
2. Then checking if we had seen already the any line with the same 2nd and 6th columns and if so, switch to the next line, else mark it as seen in an array (using the concatenated column values as indecies, **but do note** that this might fail you if you have large values in the 2nd and smalls in the 6th (e.g. `2 0020` concatenated is `20020` and it's the same for `20 020`) so you might want to add a column separatar in the index like `a[$2 "-" $6]`... and you can use more columns to check even more properly)
3. If the line has `90` on the second column prints it, flags to swap on the next line then switch to next line (in the input file)
4. On the next line checks the 2nd column in `ERRORVALUE` and if it finds, replaces its contents.
5. Then prints the formated line.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Glenn that two passes over the file is nicer. You can remove your duplicate, perhaps nonconsecutive, lines using a hash like this:

`awk '!a[$2,$3,$4,$5,$6]++' file.txt`

You should then edit your values as desired. If you wish to change the value `90` in the second column to `5000`, try something like this:

`awk 'NR == 1 { print; next } { sub(/^90$/, "5000", $2); printf("%4i% 8i% 3i% 5i% 9.4f% 6i\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) }' file.txt`

You can see that I stole Zsolt's printf statement (thanks Zsolt!) for the formatting, but you can edit this if necessary. You can also pipe the output from the first statement into the second for a nice one-liner:

`cat file.txt | awk '!a[$2,$3,$4,$5,$6]++' | awk 'NR == 1 { print; next } { sub(/^90$/, "5000", $2); printf("%4i% 8i% 3i% 5i% 9.4f% 6i\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) }'`

Answer (score 0):

The previous options work for the most part, however here's the way I would do it, simple and sweet. After reviewing the other posts I believe this would be the most efficient. In addition this also allows for the extra request the OP added in the comments to have the line after 90 replaced with a variable from 2 lines prior. This does it all in a single pass.

```
BEGIN {
    PC2=PC6=1337
    replacement=5
}
{
    if( $6 == PC6 ) next
    if( PC2 == 90 ) $2 = replacement
    replacement = PC2
    PC2 = $2 
    PC6 = $6
    printf "%4s%8s%3s%5s%9s%6s\n",$1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6
}
```

Example Input

```
   1      70  0    0   0.0000 57850
   2      31  0    0   0.0000 59371
   3      41  0    0   0.0000 60909
   4      70  0    0   0.0000 61478
   5      31  0    0   0.0000 62999 
   6      41  0    0   0.0000 64537
   7      41  0    0   0.0000 64537
   8      70  0    0   0.0000 65106
   9      11  0    0   0.0000 66627
  10      21  0    0   0.0000 68165
  11      90  0    0   0.0000 68700
  12      31  0    0   0.0000 70221
```

Example Output

```
   1      70  0    0 0.000000 57850
   2      31  0    0 0.000000 59371
   3      41  0    0 0.000000 60909
   4      70  0    0 0.000000 61478
   5      31  0    0 0.000000 62999
   6      41  0    0 0.000000 64537
   8      70  0    0 0.000000 65106
   9      11  0    0 0.000000 66627
  10      21  0    0 0.000000 68165
  11      90  0    0 0.000000 68700
  12      21  0    0 0.000000 70221
```